# Game Center Challenges in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, game-center, gamekit

I'm Converting my game from Objective-C into Swift. I noted methods from Game Center Challenges are not available in Swift. I went back to the official apple docs and couldn't find the code in Swift.

Is Game Center Challenges handled in Swift? Or is it handled automatically?

Here are the methods. (Note: Gamekit is imported)

```
- (void)player:(GKPlayer *)player didCompleteChallenge:(GKChallenge *)challenge issuedByFriend:(GKPlayer *)friendPlayer {
}
- (void)player:(GKPlayer *)player issuedChallengeWasCompleted:(GKChallenge *)challenge byFriend:(GKPlayer *)friendPlayer {
}
- (void)player:(GKPlayer *)player wantsToPlayChallenge:(GKChallenge *)challenge {
}
- (void)player:(GKPlayer *)player didReceiveChallenge:(GKChallenge *)challenge {
}
```

Comment: Please be specific. Which methods are you saying are unavailable in Swift?